Anova.glm procedure - results different between Type II and Type III settings for glm but not lm?
When using Anova to determine significance of factors in general linear models it is known that type II and type III settings will produce the same results when the design is balanced.
However, when applied on generalized linear models and using deviance as the dispersion measure, type II and type III settings yield different results (when using the function Anova.glm() from the car package) even when the design is balanced. I am wondering why that is the case ...?
I experimented this using the following code in R:
library(car)
FacA=c("A1","A2")  ### two levels of factor A
FacB=c("B1","B2","B3")  ### three levels of factor B

dft=c()
for (nA in 1:length(FacA)){
  for (nB in 1:length(FacB)){
    FacA0=FacA[nA]
    FacB0=FacB[nB]
    y=rpois(n=10,lambda=10) ## n = 10 observation with Poisson distribution
    df0=c()
    df0=data.frame(A=FacA0,B=FacB0,y=y)
    dft=rbind(dft,df0)
  }
}

### so dft is a simulated df of a balanced design 

mt2=glm(y~A+B+A:B,contrasts=list(A="contr.sum",B="contr.sum"),family=poisson(link="log"),data=dft)
mt3=lm(y~A+B+A:B,contrasts=list(A="contr.sum",B="contr.sum"),data=dft)


########### Anova on mt3, which is a lm
Anova(mt3,type="II")
Anova(mt3,type="III") 
##### they will give the same results

########### Anova on mt2, which is a glm
Anova(mt2,type="II")
Anova(mt2,type="III") 

#### they are different

So does it mean that even in balanced design, type II and III settings of Anova.glm() will generally give different results? I don't quite understand why this is the case as the design matrix in mt2 is orthogonal ... so whats the difference between type II and type III in partitioning the dispersion?
